# Change menu elements when window size less than

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scroll

I'm trying to make one site, but I have one problem (sort of). I've achieved effect as I wanted (like in myprovence.fr) - snap after scroll. This works only, if window size is bigger than 939 (basically it has to be full hd monitor). In that way there is everything OK.
But if window size is less than 939 I want to do normal scroll but with fully working navigation - when you hit (scroll to) another section - menu point changes to active (here's an [example](http://vandelaydesign.com/demos/single-page/)).
How can I do that? I'm kind of fresh with jQuery & js.

I'm trying to do it on this [site](http://in.codelab.lt/pr/) (navigation scripts are in main.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use CSS `@media queries` instead?

```
@media all and (max-width: whatever px) and (min-width: whatever px) {
  /*Classes and Id's, elements goes here*/
}
```